# Advanced Custom Field True/False field not working

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

```
<?php if( have_rows('team_members') ): ?>
    <?php while( have_rows('team_members') ): the_row(); ?>
        <div class="team-member-section">   
            <div class="container">
                <?php if( get_row_layout() == 'team_members' ): ?>
                    <section class="team-member-section">                                   
                        <?php 
                            $team_title = get_sub_field('team_title');
                            $team_member = get_sub_field('team_member');
                            $description = get_sub_field('description');
                        ?>
                        <div class="team-title">
                            <?php echo $team_title; ?>
                        </div>
                         <?php if( $team_member ): ?>
                            <?php if ( get_field('has_description') == 'yes') : ?>
                                <?php echo 'has_description'; ?>
                            <?php  else : ?>
                                <?php echo 'has_no_description'; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>  
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </section>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It displays only the value "has_no_description", why is my true/false field not working and how to make it work so both situations will be displayed.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

```
<?php if( have_rows('team_members') ): ?>
<?php while( have_rows('team_members') ): the_row(); ?>
    <div class="team-member-section">   
        <div class="container">
            <?php if( get_row_layout() == 'team_members' ): ?>
                <section class="team-member-section">                                   
                    <?php 
                        $team_title = get_sub_field('team_title');
                        $team_member = get_sub_field('team_member');
                        $description = get_sub_field('description');
                    ?>
                    <div class="team-title">
                        <?php echo $team_title; ?>
                    </div>
                     <?php if( $team_member ): ?>
                        <?php if ( get_field('has_description') ) : ?>

                        <?php foreach( $team_member as $post): ?>
                            <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="team-member">
                                        <div class="member-img">
                                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                                        <?php echo "Has description"; ?>
                                        <?php $overlay_text = get_field('overlay_text'); ?>

                                        <?php if($overlay_text != ''): ?>
                                            <div class="overlay-text">
                                                <p><?php echo $overlay_text; ?></p>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        <?php  else : ?>
                        <?php foreach( $team_member as $post): ?>
                            <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="team-member">
                                        <div class="member-img">
                                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                                        <?php echo "Doesn not have description"; ?>
                                        <?php $overlay_text = get_field('overlay_text'); ?>

                                        <?php if($overlay_text != ''): ?>
                                            <div class="overlay-text">
                                                <p><?php echo $overlay_text; ?></p>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                         <?php endforeach; ?>

                        <?php endif; ?>  
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </section>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I posted my entire code. 
I think the issue here is that the field 'has_description' is showed only on "Team" Custom Post Type and that's why the field is returning null, but I am not sure. Can someone make it work?

Comment: <?php if ( get_field('has_description') == 'yes') : ?> ,here I am using the field 'has_description'

Comment: has_description is a true/false type and it appears as a checkbox.

Comment: Unfotunately no, it only displays the else branch.

Comment: can you show output of `var_dump( get_field('has_description'));`?

Comment: The output is NULL

Comment: that's the problem that either you are not able to fetch that column  value or  you have added a default value `NULL` to the column and every-time `NULL` only is added  not true/false

Comment: Please see my update

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if( have_rows('team_members') ): ?>
<?php while( have_rows('team_members') ): the_row(); ?>
    <div class="team-member-section">   
        <div class="container">
            <?php if( get_row_layout() == 'team_members' ): ?>
                <section class="team-member-section">                                   
                    <?php 
                        $team_title = get_sub_field('team_title');
                        $team_member = get_sub_field('team_member');
                        $description = get_sub_field('description');
                    ?>
                    <div class="team-title">
                        <?php echo $team_title; ?>
                    </div>
                     <?php if( $team_member ): ?>
                        <?php foreach( $team_member as $post): ?>
                            <?php if ( get_field('has_description') ) : ?>
                            <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="team-member">
                                        <div class="member-img">
                                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                                        <?php echo "Has description"; ?>
                                        <?php $overlay_text = get_field('overlay_text'); ?>

                                        <?php if($overlay_text != ''): ?>
                                            <div class="overlay-text">
                                                <p><?php echo $overlay_text; ?></p>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                            <?php  else : ?>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="team-member">
                                        <div class="member-img">
                                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                                        <?php echo "NOOOOOOO Description"; ?>
                                        <?php $overlay_text = get_field('overlay_text'); ?>

                                        <?php if($overlay_text != ''): ?>
                                            <div class="overlay-text">
                                                <p><?php echo $overlay_text; ?></p>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>  
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </section>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

It works like this, I moved the true/false  `<?php if ( get_field('has_description') ) : ?>` field inside the foreach since true/false field belongs to the team custom post type, being out of the loop will always make it NULL